# Slick, поочередная смена слайдов?

Tags: slick.js, slider-slick.js

есть 5 слайдеров с фотографиями( Все инициализируются один раз, так как общий класс)
Вот код слайдера

```
$('.custom-photos__slides').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
  })
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать такой функционал. Меняется слайд первого слайдера, проходит секунда, меняется слайд второго слайдера, проходит секунда, меняется слайд третьего слайдера и так далее. А когда доходит до последнего слайда, начинается заново. Сами слайдеры цикличны и такой функционал получается бесконечным. Вопрос лишь в том как заставить их менять поочередно

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно. 
1) Это очень плохая мысль цеплять все слайдеры на один исполняющий класс.
2) Я бы делал так. Сделал бы некую функцию. запуска слайдеров.

```js
function startSlider(el, del) {
  el.slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    speed: 300 + del
  })
}
startSlider($(".slider1"), 0);
startSlider($(".slider2"), 1000);
startSlider($(".slider3"), 2000);
startSlider($(".slider4"), 3000);
startSlider($(".slider5"), 4000);
```

а дальше просто имитировал задержку через скорость пролистывания.(В документации delay я чёт не нашел).
Ещё можно поробовать через привязку одного слайдера к другому...
....
asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
...
asNavFor: '.slider-for'

Последний пример в документации